# What is the real meaning of "Sri Rama Jayam"?

Tags: ramayana, rama, mantras

Each word of Sri Rama Jayam has a meaning and is associated with god. I want to know What is the real meaning of Sri Rama Jayam?

Comment: Is it a slogan ? Shri Rama Jayam like jai shri ram or some stotra associated to shri ram

Comment: Please elaborate the question. I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: @Rudhra you could edit by asking about origin of this phrase.

Comment: A good ref on the topic: http://jayasreesaranathan.blogspot.in/2010/01/why-do-we-write-sri-rama-jayam-in.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rama Nama has come into existence much before the birth of Lord Sri Rama. The word RAMA when divided into syllables Ra + Aa + Ma; is said to indicate Ra means Rudra; Aa means Brahma; Ma means Vishnu and the three Trinal lords Brahma, Vishnu and Maheswara put together is RAMA.

The word RAMA is a confluence of two letters Ra + Ma. It is believed and said that these two letters are Jeevaakshara (life giving letters) carved out of the most significant hymns Narayana Ashtakshari and Shiva Panchakshari. The letter Ra is carved out of Narayana Ashtakshari “Om! Namo! Narayanaya” and the letter Ma is carved out of Shiva Panchakshari “Om! Namah Shivaya.”

These two letters (Ra+Ma) called life giving letters the soul of these two powerful hymns are put together to form the Tharaka manthra RAMA. Without these two letters (Ra+Ma) these manthras becomes ineffective. Any one chanting Tharaka manthra (RAMA) is equivalent to worshiping both Lord Vishnu as well as Lord Shiva.

"Jayam" means "Victory" in Sanskrit.

The mythological references states that the name of Rama is more strong and divine than the Lord Rama himself.

Vedas tell that as the sun dispels the darkness, the chanting of Rama Nama dispels all evil and obstacles of life. It is a way of liberation and salvation of human suffering.

Comment: You should cite sources.